# Ion returning XML error whereas expecting JSON

Tags: java, android, android-ion

I am using Ion library to send JsonArray to the web service and get JSOn output. The same url and and input are working well on postman giving the correct result. But when supplied the same url and input through Ion library, it is giving the Request error in xml format.

Please help me to get rid of this, following the code i am using

```
Ion.with(PracticalExam.this)
            .load(url)
            .setJsonArrayBody(jsonArray)
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result)
                {
                    String error=null;
                    System.out.println("RESPONSE===> "+result);
                }
            });
```

Below is the response I get

```
`���<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://json.ezeetest.in/EZEEService.svc/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'Incoming message for operation 'PracticalResult' (contract 'IEZEEService' with namespace 'http://tempuri.org/') contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Json'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpStreamFormatter.GetStreamFromMessage(Message message, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpStreamFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

I tried following as per the suggestions but still getting null result

```
Ion.with(PracticalExam.this)
            .load("POST",url)
            .addQuery("action", "dummyAction")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .setJsonArrayBody(jsonArray)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result)
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    System.out.println("Result=> " + result);
                    System.out.println("Exception=> "+e);
                }
            });
```

Comment: what is the error ?  please post the response that you get

Comment: please see the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ion did not work for me, hence i did it using AsyncTask, Below is the code

```
public class SendJsonArrayToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    String jsonData;
    private String JsonResponse;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setMessage("Saving...");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String jsonResponse = null;
        String jsonData = params[0];

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(jsonData);
            writer.close();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
            if (buffer.length() == 0)
            {
                // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            JsonResponse = buffer.toString();

            //send to post execute
            return JsonResponse;


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pd.dismiss();

    }
```

and call AsyncTask using

```
new SendJsonArrayToServer().execute(String.valueOf(jsonArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple URI connection there is property for requesting:

```
setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Can you Specify this property of connection

Comment: URLConnection conn = mUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

Please check in your case.